# Chat on raspberry pi using ssh

Tags: ssh, putty

I have a Raspberry pi 2 B+, I have enabled ssh and modem port forwarding, my friend and I are both connecting to the raspberry pi using putty, and now trying to chat using: `write`, `talk` and `ytalk`. However it is not working.

Comment: Are you saying that both you and your friend have used SSH to connect to the same Raspberry Pi and that you are unable to use `write`, `talk` and `ytalk` to communicate?  What error do you receive?

Comment: I have the same problem, it just sits there saying "[waiting for connection...]"  .. no problem loging into the system remotely, using ssh etc ..

Answer (score 3):

You could always open up a `screen` session and have the other party connect to it 
using

```
screen -x
```

Make sure both of you are logged in as the same user. When you do that, what the other party types will be visible on both `screen` connections.

Comment: ...visible on both screen connections *in real time*, which is cool if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just chat in the terminal, feel free to look at the other responses, but if you're looking to create a fully-featured chat server, check out [InspIRCd](http://www.inspircd.org/).